# What is the difference between web servers (apache,ignix etc) and web frameworks(flask,rails etc)?

Tags: webserver, terminology

Aren't both necessarily the same thing? While frameworks seem to have extra features to help ease development?

Comment: They do different things. One builds on the other. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server vs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework

Answer (score 0):

> A web server is a program that takes a request to your website from a user and does some processing on it. Then, it might give the request to your Rails app.
>
> An app server is the thing that actually runs your Rails app.

See more in http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/a-web-server-vs-an-app-server/